# Counter effect for 404 page using FlipClock js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to use counter effect like http://flipclockjs.com/faces/counter
for my 404 page, where every number should get flip multiple times and then stop to 404 number

Thank you in advance

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clock; 
 $(document).ready(function() { 
  // Instantiate a counter
  clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 900, {
   clockFace: 'Counter',
   //autoStart: true,
   countdown: false,
  });
  clock.setCountdown(true);
  clock.stop(function () {
   // this (optional) callback will fire after the clock stops
   clock.setTime(404);
  });
 });
</script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flipclockjs.com/_themes/flipclockjs/css/flipclock.css">
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://flipclockjs.com/_themes/flipclockjs/js/flipclock/flipclock.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by flip multiple times? what numbers should it flip?

Comment: @Stacklearner : I have to flip number from 999 to 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this :D

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  // Instantiate a counter
  var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(390, {
    clockFace: 'Counter'
  });
 var incrementer = 0;
  setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      incrementer++;
      clock.time.time =Math.floor( Math.random() * (404 - 100)) + 100;
      if (incrementer == 20){
        clock.time.time = 403
      }
       if (incrementer <= 20){
       clock.increment();
       }
      
        
    }, 600);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flipclockjs.com/_themes/flipclockjs/css/flipclock.css">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://flipclockjs.com/_themes/flipclockjs/js/flipclock/flipclock.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Counter</h1>
  <div class="clock"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But all the number should get flip and stop to 404

Comment: updated script , you can click on run code and check

Comment: Thanks for your replay, number get flipped but when 404 number appears it appearing with slow speed